# How to Reduce Repeated If/Else Logic in Code

Tags: apex, bestpractice, design-patterns

I'm relatively new to Apex, and one thing I've found is there are a few places in my code where the same the same if/else logic is repeated. I.e.

```
if (first_condition) {
    // do something
} else if (second_condition) {
    // do something else
} else {
    // do something different
}
```

Here, `first_condition` and `second_condition` are the same in multiple parts of code. I think I can use Apex Factories and Flows to remove the redundant code, but I'm really unsure how to use them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Where you have repeated code, there are a number of ways of avoiding the repetition that all amount to extracting the common part and still allowing the varying part to vary. See e.g. [Avoiding Repetition](https://martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/repetition.pdf).

Little is unique to Apex - it is more about these language independent design ideas:

- language mechanisms such as [Replace Conditional with Polymorphism](https://refactoring.guru/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism)
- refactorings such as [Extract Method](https://refactoring.guru/extract-method)
- design patterns such as [Template Method](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/template-method).

Sometimes a small amount of repetition is preferable to introducing complexity. I like this quote from [Code Reuse is Not a Good Goal](https://blog.ndepend.com/code-reuse-not-good-goal/):

> Avoiding duplication is a critically important goal in software
>   development, often saving you from outsized technical debt. But
>   avoiding speculative complexity and abstraction actually has the same
>   risk profile.  You need to walk a fine line in the middle.

Some further reading:

- [The DRY obsession](http://joelabrahamsson.com/the-dry-obsession/)
- [Refactorings](https://refactoring.guru/refactoring/techniques)
- [Catalog of Design Patterns](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/catalog)

Answer (score 4):

A good design patterns is only what you need to avoid code repetitiveness/boiler plate code. There is a nice blog which beautifully describes [Visitor design pattern](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12508/Dude-are-you-still-programming-using-if-then-else). You could try to implement this. This will help you solve the ugliness of too much if-else statements. Examples in this blog are not related to apex but they can be implemented in apex easily.

Salesforce has delivered idea [Add "Switch" or "Case" Statement to Apex](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrSIAA0) in [summer 18 release](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_apex_switch_statement.htm?edition=&impact=). Now instead of writing nested if-else you can write switch statements which are better in terms of performance and code organization. Switch statements are better alternatives in some cases so you can give them a try as well.

The syntax is:

```
switch on expression {
    when value1 {       // when block 1
        // code block 1
    }   
    when value2 {       // when block 2
        // code block 2
    }
    when value3 {       // when block 3
        // code block 3
    }
    when else {       // when else block, optional
        // code block 4
    }
}
```

Comment: I still don't understand how switch case will solve code repetition problem in first place, its just beautiful way of writing if-else.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal check my updated answer, now does it look relevant?