# Alternatives for multiple If statements

Tags: apex, code, conditional, if

I need to compare the fields and depending on that if its true then update a boolean variable and if its false then capture this field and get the label and append it to a string. I have like 10-12 field values to compare, so is there a way to minimize the number of If statements we use?

```
If(obj1.var1 == obj2.var1){
  booleanVar+= true
  }else{
   stringVar+=obj1.var1
    }
If(obj1.var2 == obj2.var2){
  booleanVar+= true
  }else{
   stringVar+=obj1.var2
    }
'
'
'
'
'
If(obj1.var10 == obj2.var10){
  booleanVar+= true
  }else{
   stringVar+=obj1.var10
    }
```

Comment: Does this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/221748/how-to-reduce-repeated-if-else-logic-in-code) help?

Comment: As described in the link I can add the code which is repeating in a new method and pass fields as params and make a call to this. But I am only comparing some specific fields of a object not all the fields. How do I iterate the method with only these specific params. Any inputs pls

Answer (score 0):

A generic way to do this would be to convert your data to Map objects, and compare:

```
Map<String, Object> obj1Map = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(JSON.serialize(obj1));
Map<String, Object> obj2Map = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(JSON.serialize(obj2));
Set<String> allKeys = obj1Map.keySet().clone();
allKeys.addAll(obj2Map.keySet().clone());
String[] diff = new String[0];
Boolean match = false;
for(String key: allKeys) {
  if(obj1Map.get(key) == obj2Map.get(key)) {
    match = true;
  } else {
    diff.add(''+obj1Map.get(key));
  }
}
```

This code presumes that `obj1` and `obj2` are not null, are objects, and are not primitive values, List objects, or Set objects.

If you are using an `sObject`, you can instead use getPopulatedFieldsAsMap, which has better performance than `JSON.serialize/JSON.deserializeUntyped`, and preserves the original data types for things like date values.